# Enum method match 'default'

Tags: php, enums, php-8.1

I'm wondering if there's a more resourceful way of 'defining a default' match than what I've found in the PHP docs. The below is from https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.enumerations.methods.php

```
enum Suit implements Colorful
{
    case Hearts;
    case Diamonds;
    case Clubs;
    case Spades;

    // Fulfills the interface contract.
    public function color(): string
    {
        return match($this) {
            Suit::Hearts, Suit::Diamonds => 'Red',
            Suit::Clubs, Suit::Spades => 'Black',
        };
    }

}
```

The above isn't the best example to demonstrate the need of why I'm asking what I'm asking, couldn't think of a better example yet, but imagine for the sake of this question that there were 10 suits, 9 black and 1 red. It looks like I'd have to repeat 9 of the cases inside the color match function for 'black'... I'm hoping (and asking here if the syntax exists) that there's a way to say "default is 'black'" and only use 'red' for the one I explicity say is 'red'. Kind of sort of like how I'd be able to in a switch statement. Do PHP enums provide such syntax?

Answer (score 0):

It is not about PHP Enum as much as it is about the [`match`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.match.php) expression that supports the `default` case.

```
enum Suit implements Colorful
{
    case Hearts;
    case Diamonds;
    case Clubs;
    case Spades;

    // Fulfills the interface contract.
    public function color(): string
    {
        return match($this) {
            Suit::Hearts, Suit::Diamonds => 'Red',
            default => 'Black'
        };
    }
}

echo Suit::Clubs->color(); // Black
echo Suit::Hearts->color(); // Red
```